# get box instead of horizontal line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

- I am trying to get three different states for check box, one is tick mark, another is box and another is empty.
- in the code pen its working fine with horizontal line but how to get box instead of horizontal line.

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/avyNOd

- but in fiddle I am getting an error
  (index):418 Uncaught ReferenceError: ts is not defined
  at HTMLInputElement.onclick

  - can you tell me how to fix it.
  - providing my code below

http://jsfiddle.net/11sp1n7t/

```or-tag-here
  function ts(cb) {
  if (cb.readOnly) cb.checked=cb.readOnly=false;
  else if (!cb.checked) cb.readOnly=cb.indeterminate=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In jsFiddle, the javascript is implicitly wrapped in an event handler. It is not in the global scope.

Solution is to attach your onclick event handler in javascript, not in the HTML. You should do this anyway, jsfiddle or not.